# which configuration file works when dependencies have the same files

Tags: java

I have a project that reads a log4j.properties where log file is name as body.log, and this project has a dependency that also has a log4j.properties where log file is dependency.log.

When I ran the project, I noticed both logs are created in tomcat. But only dependency.log has contents while the other one is empty. Why so?
Thanks.

EDIT:
The web application has a controller, printing logs into dependency.log as configured in dependency log4j.properties.
The web application has a log4j.properties while it is not the actual used one.

2nd EDIT:
In war web.xml, log4j is configured as:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/log/log4j-dev.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but this project does not have a src/main/resources/conf/log/log4j-dev.properties. However the dependency project has such file. While what I have been thinking is the project should complain "no such file" instead of finding this file in one dependency, otherwise from the point of web.xml, it would be like a merge of the main project and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If they're being read off the classpath, it's essentially random which one gets picked up. You should provide your own log configuration for the final project.

Comment: "provide log config for the final project". That is exactly what I am having body.properties for. It is a war project having body.log, and classes in this war are running with dependency.log. So how to provide a "final project config"?

Comment: @Tiina A `log4j.properties` *directly in* your war should take precedence over any in jars packaged inside it.

Comment: Hi, please read the 2nd edit. Now I am looking for why it is different from what you said, and I got more odd phenomena :)